# Contradiction of the Open Mapping Theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis

I have been given the following: $T:X\to Y$, where

$X=Y=${$x=(x_1,x_2,…),∑_i|x_i|<∞$} , where $X$ and $Y$ are normed linear spaces (not Banach).

They have the following norms $\|x\|_X = \sum_i|x_i|$ and $\|x\|_Y = \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|x_n|$.

Now I have already shown that T is bounded, surjective and that for the set $O = \{x\in X : \|x\|_X < 1\}$ , we have that $T(O)$ is not open in $Y$. Now for this last statement, I am trying to show that this doesn't contradict the Open Mapping Theorem. I am not sure how to show this? Any help is appreciated.

My definition of the open mapping theorem in this case is:

*Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces and
let $T ∈ B(X, Y )$. If the mapping $T$ is surjective, then $T$ is an open mapping*.

Comment: What is the mapping $T$?

Comment: Which version of the open mapping theorem are you trying to disprove? anyhow you have to show that either your space $X$ or $Y$ doesn't satisfy the hypotheses of the theorem.

Comment: I suggest a careful checking of the hypotheses of that Theorem.   I suspect  some of them will not hold!

Comment: @SebastianCor I added the theorem I am using in this case

Answer (score 1):

It's clear that O is open in X. So if the open mapping theorem applied, then T(O) would have to be open in Y. Since the exercise asks you to prove that it's not, clearly the open mapping theorem doesn't apply. Since T is trivially surjective, one of the spaces involved is not Banach.

HINT: One of them is carrying the wrong norm. The space $Y$ is just $\ell^1$ with the $\ell^\infty$ norm. You should look for a sequence which converges in the $\ell^\infty$ norm, and whose limit is in $\ell^\infty$ but not in $\ell^1$. This gives you a Cauchy sequence without a limit.

Comment: I've been thinking about it for quite some time but am not sure what such a sequence would look like... could you give a hint on that?

Comment: Should it be of the form $x_n=(1/n,1/n,......1/n,0,......,0)$? Where you have the $1/n$ n-times?

Comment: That doesn't work, since it tends to $(0,0,0,...)$ in $\ell^\infty$. You need to think of something which tends to something that's not an element of $\ell^1$. Can you think of something that converges to $(1,1/2,1/3,...)$? That's the classic counterexample of something not in $\ell^1$.